# Where is toString() overridden on java.util.List

Tags: java, collections, junit4

I was wondering why this assert works in JUnit:

```
assertEquals("[String1, String2, String3]", Arrays.asList("String1", "String2", "String3").toString());
```

I can't see the toString() being overridden anywhere on List or Collection.

I'm glad it works, but, still curious.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns [an `Arrays#ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList) that extends `AbstractList` which extends `AbstractCollection` [which implements `toString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

toString is overrided by [AbstractCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) which is a superclass of :

- AbstractList
- AbstractQueue
- AbstractSet
- ArrayDeque

The element returned by `.asList` is probably a subclass of `AbstractList`

Answer (score 1):

Both `List` and `Collection` are interfaces. Method `toString()` is overridden in `AbstractCollection`.

Anyway it is a bad practice to compare string representations of objects. You should use

`assertEquals(expectedList, actualList)` instead.

where

`expectedList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"String1", "String2", "String3"})`

or even better in your case:

`assertArrayEquals(expectedArray, actualArray)`

Please pay attention that you should use newer `org.junit.Assert` instead of `junit.framework.Assert`. The new implementation has a lot of methods including array comparison utilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you got to `asList` code(pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> on `asList` goes to the declaration in eclipse is the source code is attached) it returns

```
 return new ArrayList<T>(a);
```

And investigating further [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) does have a `toString` overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` class has implementation of `toString()`. Since every class directly or indirectly `extends` to `Object`, If a particular class doesn't define toString(), it gets inherited from it's parent classes in the hierarchy.

**UPDATED** based on [UmNyobe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1122645/umnyobe) comments:

In the hierarchy, the very first parent class found which has the required omplementation, will be used. In the question by OP, that parent class will be `AbstractCollection` which overrides `toString` from `Object`.

Comment: Why not? I guess you are mistaken that i meant to say that it come from `Object`. If yes, let me know, i'll rephrase.

Comment: Indeed, I was mistaken to think that way.

Answer (score -2):

`toString` is overriden by `ArrayList`, the `List` implementation returned by `Arrays.asList()`

Here is how the `asList` method is implemented in the `Arrays` class.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

where `ArrayList` is an static inner class of `Arrays`:

`private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>`

Ya, well is not directly overriden by `ArrayList` but by its ancestor `AbstractList`

Comment: arraylist doesn't override toString.

Comment: You should be aware that the `ArrayList` returned in `Arrays#asList()` is not the same as `java.util.ArrayList`. It is returning `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` which is a `private static class`.

Comment: to the unknown 3rd downvoter: if there was an unclarity in the answer it was corrected before

Comment: *"well is not directly overriden by ArrayList but by its ancestor AbstractList"* => it is actually overriden in AbstractCollection, which is the parent class of AbstractList.